# regexp to replace start/end symbols multiple times across the string

Tags: javascript, regex

as a newbie to regexp, i'm not able to construct regexp to accomplish following task:

The string:

```
(q[1]="one" and q[2]="two")
```

Desired result:

```
(q[1].indexOf("one") and q[2].indexOf("two"))
```

Thus regexp should replace `="` with `.indexOf("` combination along with any character followed by `"` with `")`

Thank for Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str = '(q[1]="one" and q[2]="two")';
str = str.replace(/=("[^"]+")/g, '.indexOf($1)')
```

this sets str to

```
(q[1].indexOf("one") and q[2].indexOf("two"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var str = '(q[1]="one" and q[2]="two")';  // use let instead of var if it's available
var newstr = str.replace(/=(".+?")/g, '.indexOf($1)');
```

Note that, while my solution is pretty much the same as dystroy's, it uses a slightly different regular expression. `+?` is a non-greedy match, meaning rather than matching as much as possible it matches as little as possible (so when searching string `"a"b"` for a match, `/".+"/` would result in `"a"b"` while `/".+?"/` would result in `"a"`).

Comment: Yeah, this is interesting, I'm gonna have to remember this. Is there any performance/real difference between using this or dystroy's regex?

Comment: @ian Yes, actually. I just noticed that mine will match `="""` while dystroy's will not, though neither will match `=""`. Given that the original string appears to be a code snippet, however, `="""` in the string would have resulted in a syntax error or unexpected behavior somewhere anyway.

Comment: @JAB Ahh I see. If you change your `+` to `*`, you can match `=""` but then no longer matches `="""`. I doubt that's important to the OP